# How post form data, collect data generate and then redirect to a page?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post

I have a form which POST's data, I then need to collect this data which I know how to do using

```
$billingaddress = $post['firstname']
```

Then after collecting the post data I need to redirect to a set URL

```
header(Location: www.google.com);
```

I am just unsure on the setup of which files need to contain what code in terms I need to need to collect the data and simulatously redirect (it will go to sagepay)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to use it.

```
//Posted data stored in $_POST global array
$billingaddress = $_POST['firstname'];
//Do what you want.
//Need to add quotes around the parameter
//Need to use full URL started with the schema (http|https).
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
//Terminate the script after redirect.
exit;
```

**Note**: Are you sure you want to collect the firstname into a variable called billingaddress? That is a bad practice. Call your variables what it includes, eg: `$firstName`

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer ill give it ago. Yeah it was just an example I will amend the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but from one another question somewhere in the void of the internet, I managed to find a good form setup. You need 3 files: `nameofform.php`, `nameofredirectpage.html`, and a place to store the data. Here's an example from one of my sites.

## The Form Page

```
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $errorMessage = "";
    /* This section determines the error messages if there is a blank field. */
    if(empty($_POST['formSteam']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You need to put your Steam ID!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formName']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Please put your first and/or lastname!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formAge']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Please tell us your age! This is just for reference.</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formPos']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You need to give us what position you want!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formApplication']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Do I have to explain this? Please explain why you want to be apart of our staff!</li>";
    }
    /* This section just labels the variables. */
    $varSteam = $_POST['formSteam'];
    $varName = $_POST['formName'];
    $varAge = $_POST['formAge'];
    $varApplication = $_POST['formApplication'];
        $varPos = $_POST['formPos'];
   /* This is where the magic happens. It's saying that if there is no errors and all the fields are filled in, it will open [or create] the file mydata.csv, which then writes each variable; `$varSteam`, `$varName`, `$varAge`, and so on. Grabbing what the fields content were, it will post the data in the specified order on the [newly created] file, then close the document. Finally, it redirects the user to the selected page, in this case "success.html". */
    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
        fwrite($fs,$varSteam . ", " . $varName . ", " . $varAge . ", " . $varPos . ", " . $varApplication . "\n");
        fclose($fs);

        header("Location: success.html");
        exit;
    }
}
?> 
<html>
<body>

    <?php
        if(!empty($errorMessage)) 
        {
            echo("<p>There was an error with your form:</p>\n");
            echo("<ul>" . $errorMessage . "</ul>\n");
        } 
    ?>
    /* This is the field ; change accordingly! */
    <form action="application.php" method="post">
        <p>
            Whats your Steam ID? Find out <a href="http://www.steamidfinder.com">here!</a><br>
            <input type="text" name="formSteam" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varSteam;?>">
        </p>
        <p>
            What is your name?<br>
            <input type="text" name="formName" maxlength="50" value="<?=$varName;?>">
        </p>                
        <p>
                How old are you?<br>
                <input type="text" name="formAge" maxlength="2" value="<?=$varAge;?>">
        </p>
        <p>
                What position are you applying for?<br>
                <select name="formPos" value="<?=$varPos;?>">
                            <option value="">Pick an Option</option>
                            <option value="moderator">Moderator</option>
                            <option value="coder">Coder</option>
                            <option value="admin">Administrator</option>
                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            Why do you want to apply for PossessedGaming Staff? *NOTE: If the above option was "OTHER", please include that "OTHER" position.<br>
            <textarea name="formApplication" maxlength="3000" style="width:325px;height:150px;" value="<?=$varApplication;?>"></textarea>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## The Redirected Page

```
<html>


  <body>
        <center>
          <h1>Success!</h1>
          <p>Your application will be reviewed by the staff ASAP. Thanks for applying!</p>
      </body>

    </html>
```

The example I used was a staff-application form for my site; you can probably modify it accordingly. Again, not sure if this is what you wanted, but... yeah.